# Clojure: How to reductions with a predicate?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, how do I do `reductions` with a `predicate`?

For example:

```clj
(reductions - 1000 [500 600 300 90 180 180 30 80])
```

I want: (1) subtraction to be executed only if the subtrahend is not greater than the minuend; (2) if the condition in (1) is not met, leave the minuend as it is. Thus, the result should be:

```clj
=> (500 500 200 110 110 80 0)
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your logic in a function and use that instead of `-`:

```
user> (defn f [a b] (if (>= a b) (- a b) a))
#'user/f

user> (reductions f 1000 [500 600 300 90 180 180 30 80])
(1000 500 500 200 110 110 110 80 0)
```

`reduction` includes the initial value at the head of the result, you can use `rest` or `next` if you don't want it. Also I get `110` three times, which is different than your requested output, but I think it's correct according to your rules.

Or if you prefer to use an anonymous function:

```
(reductions #(if (> %1 %2) (- %1 %2) %1) 1000 [500 600 300 90 180 180 30 80])
```